# How make CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") referring to the currently activated instance of IE?

Tags: com, vbscript, automation, activex

I am developing a browser auto-testing tool using vbscript . 
I want  to inject the jquery.js code to the currently activated running instance of Internet Explorer.
The default behavior of CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") is to create a new IE instance. How can I make an COM object referring to the currently activated instance of Internet Explorer rather than creating a new one?

Comment: have you tried `GetObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`?

Comment: I tried  GetObject("InternetExplorer.Application").no luck..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/941767/69820

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add comma first `GetObject(,"InternetExplorer.Application")`