# Using VBA to send url to an active IE window

Tags: internet-explorer, vba

I'm working in VBA and creating Macros in Excel to send info to and from an IE browser window. 
I've been using AppActivate to focus on the certain IE page using it's title which has worked fine. 
Using SendKeys to send information back to the browser hasn't 100% gone that well so I've now started using...

```
Set ie = New InternetExplorer

ie.Navigate "http://url"

'Loop until ie page is fully loaded
Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

ie.Visible = True
```

followed by code to populate various fields on a web form.

This all works really well now except that it is currently set to open a new browser window. 
I've been trying to change the code so it finds the IE window I'm using similarly to AppActivate. But I can't find a way of combining the two. 
Can anyone help please? 
How do I change.....

```
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
```

to

```
Set ie = IE WINDOW WITH THIS TITLE.... or something similar?
```

Many thanks

Paul

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941767/reusing-internet-explorer-com-automation-object

Answer (score 1):

Please read this link in order to get an IE window by its address

http://vba-corner.livejournal.com/4623.html

Here is another useful link

http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/ie-automation.shtml

Hope is helps

Comment: Thank you for that. I've managed to do it now by exploring a few forums. I'm now using  Dim ie As Object

With CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
etc which is working great. Thanks for the response