# Checking Busy Status of Open IE Windows

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

I am very new to Vbscript, however its one of the only tools available to me at my current employment. We have a web based system that I am trying to interact with. The web page reloads frequently. Such as choosing a drop down box the page will hang for a moment while it reloads the page. My script currently pauses for a few seconds between each command, but sometimes does not wait long enough. I was wondering if I could create an IE object from the existing window and check its busy status. So when its done processing I could move on to the next command.

I have already tried:
Set IE = GetObject(, "internetexplorer.application")
however it gives me an error that: ActiveX component can't create object 'GetObject'

I have spend a great deal of time searching google and a few other places to see if there is a simple alternative but have found none. this is going to be an HTA application.

Comment: I forgot to mention, it is IE7 windows XP.

Comment: tried to do such things in vbscript and HTA in the past, will never be reliable.
Now i use ruby, easily to install also on windows and is a dream to work with, especially in combination with the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than try to use `GetObject` to latch on to existing instance you can use the code at  this link [reusing Internet Explorer COM Automation Object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/941767/641067)

But instead I think you should you an approach like below which checks for the `ReadyState` of the automated ie object being ready

```
Dim ieObject
Set ieObject = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
ieObject.Navigate "www.google.com"
Do While ieObject.readystate <> 4
WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
```