# VBscript Object required 800A01A8

Tags: windows, vbscript

Please help. cant make this code work. It requires an object. Don't know how to resolve this. I see no typo error on my script. I am trying to check if there is an Internet Explorer that is open to https://www.test.com in my PC. Badly needed for a school project. Thanks in advance

```
Option Explicit
Dim objShell, objShellWindows, i, objIE
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows

For i = 0 to objShellWindows.Count - 1
    Set objIE = objShellWindows.Item(i)
    strURL = objIE.LocationURL
    If InStr(strURL, "https://www.test.com/")Then
        blnFound = True
    End If
Next
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want a vbscript that will check if there is an open internet explorer on my PC.. If there is, then it will check if that IE is open to a particular website.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/941853/3898606

Comment: Thanks, but it returns the same error I am encountering while using my script above.. What I really wonder is that I am having an error on the line 8 of my script "strURL = objIE.LocationURL" it says object required objIE.

Comment: it might be enough to check that objIE is not `Nothing`, like the VBScript example on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773970(v=vs.85).aspx#code-snippet-3

Comment: `strURL` isnt defined. Since you have `Option Explicit` you need to declare all variables. Perhaps you just need `Dim strURL`?

Comment: @Matt Good point, but that would raise a different error (800A01F4, variable is undefined).

Comment: The only error I get when running the above code is the `Variable is undefined`. Once i defined it the code appears to be running as intended on Window 7 x64 SP1 Professional. Is this all of your code? You should have gotten the same error as me. I am aware that it is not the root cause of your issue however I wonder why you are able to execute that code without the `800A01F4, variable is undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Below code will check all the URLs loaded in the IE, 
Note that here `bFound` is True when `sURL` is inside `.LocationURL`, not begin with. Modify to suit your need.

```
Option Explicit

Const sURL = "https://www.test.com/"
Dim oShell, oWindow, oIE, bFound
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
bFound = False
For Each oWindow In oShell.Windows
    If InStr(1,oWindow.Fullname,"iexplore.exe",vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Set oIE = oWindow
        With oIE
            'Wscript.Echo .LocationURL
            bFound = (InStr(1,.LocationURL,sURL,vbTextCompare) > 0)
            If bFound Then Exit For
        End With
        Set oIE = Nothing
    End If
Next
If bFound Then
    Wscript.Echo sURL & " is loaded"
Else
    Wscript.Echo sURL & " is NOT loaded"
End If
Set oShell = Nothing
```

Comment: Do **NOT** use global `On Error Resume Next`. **EVER.** If for some reason you must use `OERN`, do it as localized as possible, and put sensible error handlers in place.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Did I say we should put `OERN` at global level? I assumes the user to use it in a local Sub. If you did down vote this, please reconsider. I have removed OERN now as very beginning of code I needed it to test for an Object being Nothing. I believe DownVote is for Answers that does not relate to the question, not style of coding practise.

Comment: Putting a global `OERN` in an answer without due warning or any kind of error handling is setting a bad example. Keep in mind that most people asking for VBScript help here know very little about VBScript and its pitfalls.