# How to Zoom in or Zoom out in a webpage while using UFT/QTP

Tags: vbscript, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft

I would like to control the zoom in and out feature of my webpage of the application under test using UFT. This is required as the zoom level changes dynamically and it becomes difficult to identify the objects.
I have found a code but it is useful if you need to change the zoom level at one instance or at the start. below is the code

```
Function ChangeIEZoom
Dim intZoomLevel, objIE
intZoomLevel = 110
 Const OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM = 63
 Const OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
 Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 objIE.Visible = True
 objIE.Navigate ("www.google.com")
 While objIE.Busy = True
 wait 5
 Wend
 objIE.ExecWB OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, CLng(intZoomLevel), vbNull
End Function
```

with this code, it opens up a new browser and navigates it to a URL.

I do not want it to create a new instance of the browser.
What I need is that it changes the zoom level on the same page which is already under test execution, also the page where zoom level change is required not known at the start and it may or may not require change based on the fact that it identifies certain objects.

Has anyone faced the same issue or has a solution to it ?

Comment: If the main point is that you want to get rid of the new instance creation, using an existing IE instance, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941767/reusing-internet-explorer-com-automation-object (first answer, third option) for a possible solution.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I want to change zoom level in my application in the middle of the test run. I do not want new instance creation, i want to change zoom level on the current webpage that is under test.

Comment: Thank you @TheBlastOne - Based on your comments I was able to find a solution

Comment: Glad to be helpful! And thanks for sharing the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution - combining what you mentioned in comments. this works if you want to change the zoom level on current webpage you are working on. helps when you want to zoom in and out at multiple instances

```
Dim ShellApp
Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim ShellWindows
Set ShellWindows = ShellApp.Windows()
Dim intZoomLevel
intZoomLevel = 110
Const OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM = 63
Const OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
Dim i
For i = 0 To ShellWindows.Count - 1
    If InStr(ShellWindows.Item(i).FullName, "iexplore.exe") <> 0 Then
        Set IEObject = ShellWindows.Item(i) 
    End If
    If IEObject.Visible = True Then
    While IEObject.Busy = True
     wait 5
    Wend
     IEObject.ExecWB OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, CLng(intZoomLevel), vbNull    
    End If
Next
print "it works"
```