# Zoom to 100% on a webpage (HP UFT)

Tags: zooming, qtp, hp-uft

I'm fairly new to using HP UFT Version 12.54

So I was wondering if there was a code to use to zoom the webpage to 100%? Because sometimes when someone else uses my desktop they would change the resolution of the webpage to random numbers like 80% or 75% because they need it for their code.
I'm tired of changing it manually every time so I want to find out if there was a code for this?
The webpage I'm using is Internet Explorer

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Oh and i don't need the windows to be resized, just the actual zoom level of the webpage, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Zoom in or Zoom out in a webpage while using UFT/QTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018099/how-to-zoom-in-or-zoom-out-in-a-webpage-while-using-uft-qtp)

Comment: Check out my answer on - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018099/how-to-zoom-in-or-zoom-out-in-a-webpage-while-using-uft-qtp

Comment: hello! i just checked it out, but for some reason it doesnt work when i run the code, do i need to change something?

Comment: Post the code here which you are using and the details of the error you are getting.

Comment: Check this answer, it might be helpful <br> [How to Zoom in or Zoom out in a webpage while using UFT/QTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018099/how-to-zoom-in-or-zoom-out-in-a-webpage-while-using-uft-qtp)